# Virtual layer with spatial query crashes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-join, virtual-layer

Working with QGIS 3.10. Details:

[image]

This should be really simple, but I am unable to solve it:
I've got a point layer with two numeric fields `"max"` and `"min"`, and a polygon layer. I want to create a Virtual layer with the polygons and the sums of "max" and "min" of the points that are within each polygon. All my tries around the following code result in QGIS crash

```
SELECT polygon.name,
       polygon.geometry,
       SUM(point.max) AS maxim,
       SUM(point.min) AS minim
FROM polygon
JOIN point ON st_within (point.geometry, polygon.geometry) = 1
GROUP BY polygon.name, polygon.geometry
```

My layers have shapefiles as their data source.

Answer (score 3):

For me, your query works as expected, see:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdgsd.png]

So the problem does not have to do with your query, but with your layer/data, your project, your QGIS installation or your machine. Without more details, it's difficult to say what caused the problem.

But you can also create new fields with aggregated `minim` and `maxim` attributes for points grouped by polygons using QGIS expressions. You can use virtual fields to have dynamic changes.

1. On the point layer, create a new field `within_polygon` with this expression:

```
if (
    length (
        make_line (
            $geometry, 
            closest_point (
                array_first (
                    overlay_nearest(
                        'poly', 
                        $geometry
                    )
                ),
                $geometry
            )
        )
    ) =0 , 
    array_first (
        overlay_nearest (
            'poly', 
            name
        )
    ) , 
    false
)
```

2. On the polygon layer, create a new field `minim` with this expression (and adapting this to create maxim by simply change `expression:="min"` to `expression:="max"`

```
aggregate( 
    layer:='point', 
    aggregate:='sum', 
    expression:="min",
    filter:= 
        within_polygon = 
        attribute ( 
            @parent, 
            'name'
        )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, there must be an issue in my QGIS installation, since it doesn't work in simpler layers either.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: Are your points and polygons single part or multiparts? Multipart could be a problem.

Comment: The problem might also be a simple performance issue. Just tried my exemple from the screenshot virt virtual fields and it gets appreciably slower. Not so with virtual layer for this small example. But for layers with many features, that might be an issue.

Comment: Do your layers have a spatial index?

Comment: Version details: edit in the original post. Polygons are multipart and quite complex. Spatial index created. Needs seem to be solved with virtual fields in the polygon layer, but still wondering why the virtual layer doesn't work.

Comment: To me, the size/complexity of your geometries seems to be the most probable cause of the problem. Did you also check if you don't have geometry errors? Using PostGIS could be a solution.

Comment: Geometry validation running for the last half hour...

Comment: That substantiates the suspicion that the performance to calculate the output of the query crashed your virtual layer.

Comment: The very concept of virtual layers implies that the output is not permanent, but temporary and thus is always re-calculated, without being definitively stored. Plus you have filebased data, not a database. As mentioned: in my tiny example, virtual fields were quite slow. Creating permanent fields was fast and easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118829/discussion-between-jesus-pinilla-and-babel).